# Php doens't read json correctly

Tags: php, json

i have a big trouble using json i'm using this script to do some admin work on a telegram bot,i use json to encode some data and be able to manipulate them without touching the bot files.
I've tried searching but found nothing.
Is any way i can fix this? Where is the fault?

form code:

```
<?php
   
$bot_is_active = true;
echo '<html>';
echo '<body>';
    
echo '<form action = "form_bot_updater.php" method = "post">';
echo '<input type ="text" name = "botoken"><br>';
echo '<label for "botoken"> Insert Token Here </label>';
echo '<input type = "text" name = "filename"><br>';
    
if ($bot_is_active) {
   echo ' <input type = "checkbox" name="change_state" value = "Deactivate"> ';
   echo '<label for = "change_state"> Deactivate! </label> <br> ';
}else{
   echo ' <input type = "checkbox" name = "change_state" value = "Activate"> ';
   echo '<label for = "change_state"> Activate! </label><br> ';
}
    
echo'<input type="submit">';
echo '</form>';
    
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
    
?>
```

receiving code:

```
<?php 
  
$something_changed = false;
$change_state =$_POST ['change_state'];
$new_token = $_POST['botoken'];
$bot_filename = $_POST['filename'];

$configpointer = fopen('config.json', "r+");
$form_update = file_get_contents('config.json');
$form_update = json_decode($form_update,TRUE);


if ( isset( $new_token ) ) {
   $something_changed = true;
   $form_update["botToken"] = $new_token;
   $form_update = json_encode( $form_update );
   file_put_contents('config.json', $form_update, LOCK_EX );
} else {
   echo " Token hasn't changed \n";
}
if ( $change_state == "Deactivate" ) {
   $form_update["bot_is_active"] = false;
   $form_update = json_encode( $form_update );
   file_put_contents( 'config.json', $form_update, LOCK_EX );
} else {
   $form_update["bot_is_active"] = true;
   $form_update = json_encode( $form_update );
   file_put_contents( 'config.json', $form_update, LOCK_EX );
}

if (isset($bot_filename)) {
   if ($form_update['main_file_name'] != $bot_filename ) {
      $something_changed = true;
      $form_update['main_file_name'] = $bot_filename;
      $form_update = json_encode( $form_update );
      file_put_contents( 'config.json', $form_update, LOCK_EX );
   }
}

$current_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__)).PHP_EOL;
  
if ( $form_update['dir'] != $current_dir ) { 
   $something_changed = true;
   $form_update['dir'] = $current_dir;
   $form_update = json_encode( $form_update );
   file_put_contents( 'config.json', $form_update, LOCK_EX );
}
if ($something_changed) { 

   $webhook_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$form_update["botToken"]."/setWebhook?url=https://".$current_dir."/".$form_update['main_file_name'];

    
   echo $webhook_url;
   echo '<br>';
   echo "< a href = $webhook_url > < p > Due to changes you need to reset the webhook to your bot,click here < /p > < /a >";
    
}
fclose($configpointer);

?>
```

Json:

```
{
   "botToken" : "some token",
   "bot_is_active": true,
   "main_file_name" : "bot.php",
   "dir" : ""
}
```

And i get this out:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot"/setWebhook?url=https://bot /"
< a href = https://api.telegram.org/bot"/setWebhook?url=https://bot /" > < p > Due to changes you 
need to reset the webhook to your bot,click here < /p > < /a >
```

Comment: really, your code have a lot of undrestanding code, why you use `fopen`, then you use `file_get_contents` instead, then when the isset($new_token) is true, the final value of `$form_update` is a json code, so if `$change_state == "Deactivate"` is true, `$form_update` will be an array with false value in `"bot_is_active"` index an so on

Comment: Please explain some more,i'm not understanding.

Comment: just i want to know, what is the purpose of use `$configpointer = fopen('config.json', "r+");` ?

Comment: i thought you have to open the file before doing anything.

Comment: fopen in your code is useless,you didnt use $configpointer in your code just when you close the file. and i think you must explain more what are you looking for from your code, ﻻecause the code is not understood.

Comment: I just wanted to get the contents of the file json and use them as associative array,in encode and decode as well.